# What is the compatible version of oracle maven dependency in Spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, ojdbc

I want to create a Spring Boot application using Oracle as Database, but while updating the dependency, in the `pom.xml`, it's throwing an error.

Can someone suggest how to get the compatible version of oracle dependency for spring boot.

Or we need to manually download ojdbc6 or ojdbc7 jar file and add it to build path?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sumit.EMS</groupId>
    <artifactId>Employee-Management-System</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Employee-Management-System</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>

    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>

    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: update code here

Comment: @Deadpool I have updated pom.xml

Comment: @Sumit post error here !

Comment: @Boo Berr'ita- this error  I am getting: "Missing artifact oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven can't find a repository for this last (no public repository due binary license for those version ) ,

- So [download it](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/ojdbc6/ojdbc6.jar.zip) (ojdbc6)
- create `lib/` folder in your project and put it there
- then in `pom.xml` refer this last to you lib folder using
  `<systemPath>` (local dependency )

as below :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Or Simply use recent public  ojdbc 14 :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: ber'ita - thanks for your input, so for Oracle ojdbc6, ojdbc14 or any version we need to download and add in locally? it can not be directly downloaded by updating dependency in pom like other jar's of postgress, mysql etc database

Comment: I think yes , check and get back to you